# Is there a win32 command line tabifier that supports ... `read details` (revised)?

Tags: command-line, tabs

I use an editor that allows me to type in a command to run. In order to see the output without having to redirect it to a file, I precede the command with "cmd /k," which leaves an open cmd.exe window. So I'd  like to find a way to catch the call to cmd.exe and pass it onto an application that tabifies cmd.exe, a terminal emulator as it's called. The desired result would be similar to what happens in a tabbed editor, when that editor is to open some file, it does so in another tab, and not in another window. While in a given situation it may be easier to modify the command to redirect output to display in the editor itself, in general it would be more helpful if I could find a way to catch all such calls into one window.

Comment: By "cmd window", do you mean "console window" or "cmd.exe window"?

Comment: cmd.exe window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a program that attains the above criteria is found, this post may be edited to link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest leaving `cmd` for PowerShell. And PowerShell ISE (integrated scripting environment) which supports tabs, each of which can hold multiple files being editted) and includes a debugger.

Comment: Before I install PowerShell, would you care to explain if I'll be able to have it catch commanads like "cmd /k program" in a new tab? Or will I have to change such commands to something else? If so, what?

Comment: @user55542: In ISE control-T opens a new tab, and then run the command in that tab (each tab is a separate PSH session in the same process).

Comment: I meant I do not open a cmd window from which I type commands to run. But from an editor, for example, I might run a command to compile something. That command is going to leave a cmd window in which any compilation messages may be printed. Can I use powershell for this?

Comment: @user55542 It would rather depend on the editor (it may well be hard-coded to use `cmd.exe`).. On Windows all the editors I've used have always captured any output into one of their own Windows, so I've never really had an issue like that.

Comment: The editor just runs the command which I type, e.g. "cmd /k ..." I use cmd /k so I can see the output. I could, in this case, modify it to show output in the editor, but it'd be very helpful in general to find a way to catch such cmd instances into a single tabbed window. If I can use powershell to do that instead of cmd that's good too.

Comment: @user55542 It is clear that you are interested in something rather different to what I thought you were talking about. Please revise the question with the extra information from these comments to get better answers.

Comment: Revised, to hopefully make it clearer. Now how do I get it to the top again?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Console (aka Console2)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).