# Is there a way to catch cmd.exe windows into tabs?

Tags: windows, command-line, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a win32 command line tabifier that supports … `read details` (revised)?](https://superuser.com/questions/256603/is-there-a-win32-command-line-tabifier-that-supports-read-details-revised)

I use an editor that allows me to type in a command to run. In order to see the output without having to redirect it to a file, I precede the command with "cmd /k," which leaves an open cmd.exe window. So I'd like to find a way to move catch the call to cmd.exe and give it to an application that tabifies cmd.exe, a terminal emulator as it's called.

The desired result would be similar to what happens in a tabbed editor, when that editor is to open some file, it does so in another tab, and not in another window. While in a given situation it may be easier to modify the command to redirect output to display in the editor itself, in general it would be more helpful if I could find a way to catch all such calls into one window.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. If you don't get a suitable answer, you can edit to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have cmd windows with tabs without some kind of add-on tool.  [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) will let you have a window with multiple cmd tabs, but I don't know whether there's a way to start a tab from your editor.  Not much, but it may get you started in the right direction.